# NSError code 256 - Twitter GET

Tags: objective-c, url, twitter, error-handling, nsdata

I have this code here which *sometimes* works. I make sure that I am connected to the internet before attempting this Get from Twitter, and I am pretty sure it isn't the problem.

```
    ...
    NSString *twitterURLString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?include_entities=true&include_rts=true&screen_name=twitterapi&count=2"];NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:twitterURLString];

    NSError *error  = nil;
    NSData *dataFromURL = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url
                                            options:0
                                              error:&error];
    NSLog(@"%@", error);  
    ...
```

This returns the following :

> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=256 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa       error 256.)" UserInfo=0x4f6520 {NSURL=https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?include_entities=true&include_rts=true&screen_name=twitterapi&count=2}

I'm sure it has to do with the url encoding or something since the actual link works well. Also, it actually works sometime, with the same internet connexion (which I repeat is tested and works fine). Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!